# Border in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am creating a jasper report .In that I want apply border to the each page.Can any one provide me some help on this.Border height should depend on the contents height of that page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by creating a frame or a rectangle in an outer report and then put inside it a supreport. The subreport should be allowed to expand as it wants and the rectangle should be set to Stretch to the band height.

Answer (score 5):

You can add a full size rectangle or bordered frame to the background band.

Comment: What if I do not need the border on Page Header anf footer. Please help